# How to write a SQL query to insert from a triple many-to-one relationship to a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, many-to-many, sql-server-2008-r2

I the following two tables/columns:

```
TableA
id | data

TableB
fkeyA1 | fkeyA2 | fkeyA3 | name
```

The first three columns in TableB are foreign keys all pointing to TableA. I would like to transform TableB into the following two tables:

```
TableC
id | name

TableD
fkeyC | fkeyA
```

so that one row in TableB becomes one row in TableC plus three rows in TableD. How should I write a SQL query for this?

#### EDIT:

In `TableB`, there is a unique index on `(fkeyA1, fkeyA2, fkeyA3)`, but the `name` column does not necessarily have unique values.

Comment: Do two users with the same `name` from TableB correspond to the same Id in TableC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor statement:

```
declare @idC table(id int)
declare @fkeyC int, @fkeyA1 int, @fkeyA2 int, @fkeyA3 int, @name varchar(8)
declare CursorB cursor fast_forward for select fkeyA1, fkeyA2, fkeyA3, name from TableB
open CursorB
fetch next from CursorB into @fkeyA1, @fkeyA2, @fkeyA3, @name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    insert into TableC(name) output inserted.id into @idC values (@name)
    set @fkeyC = (select top 1 id from @idC)
    insert into TableD(fkeyC, fkeyA) values (@fkeyC, @fkeyA1), (@fkeyC, @fkeyA2), (@fkeyC, @fkeyA3)
    delete from @idC
    fetch next from CursorB into @fkeyA1, @fkeyA2, @fkeyA3, @name
end
close CursorB
deallocate CursorB
```

This may not be the best in performance, but will allow for non-unique values for the name column.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by doing an insert into tableC with `Id` being an `IDENTITY` column

```
INSERT INTO TableC(name)
SELECT b.name
FROM TableB AS b
```

I would then write an insert:

```
SELECT c.Id, b.fkeyA1
FROM TableC AS c
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON c.name = b.name
UNION    
SELECT c.Id, b.fkeyA2
FROM TableC AS c
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON c.name = b.name
UNION
SELECT c.Id, b.fkeyA3
FROM TableC AS c
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON c.name = b.name
```

Another approach for the INSERT into TableD is:

```
SELECT c.Id, a.Id
FROM TableB AS b
INNER JOIN TableC AS c ON b.name = c.name
LEFT JOIN TableA AS a ON b.fkeyA1 = a.Id
   OR b.fkeyA2 = a.Id
   OR b.fkeyA3 = a.Id
```

If tableB contains the name 'Adam' twice, Both records from B will be referenced by the same Id in TableC, and TableD will have 6 records for that Id

Eg.

```
TableA         TableB                   TableC          TableD
1, 'Data1'     1, 2, 3, 'Adam'          1, 'Adam'       1, 1
2, 'Data2'     4, 5, 6, 'Someone'       2, 'Someone'    1, 2
3, 'Data3'     7, 8, 9, 'Adam'                          1, 3
4, 'Data4'                                              1, 7
5, 'Data5'                                              1, 8
6, 'Data6'                                              1, 9
7, 'Data7'                                              2, 4
8, 'Data8'                                              2, 5
9, 'Data9'                                              2, 6
```

Comment: Logically, I don't think you need to nest the `COALESCE()` - And anyways, I think you mean `LEFT JOIN TableA as a ON b.fkeyA1 = a.Id OR b.fkeyA2 = a.Id OR b.fkeyA3 = a.Id`, your current version I believe will get some odd results...

Comment: You're absolutely right about my `LEFT JOIN` needing to be on TableB, thank you.  I'm not sure what you mean about not needing to nest the `COALESCE()` though.

Comment: The first approach, if you change the `UNION ALL` `to UNION` should work for duplicate values of name.  I do not know about my second approach, I am not near a sql-server to test.  I'll take a look near 5:00am UTC and respond then.

Comment: `COALESCE()` is a function that takes a list of arguments, there's no reason to split it up that way.  There's also no logical outcome difference when nesting - `a1` would always be preferred, regardless of the status of `a2` or `a3`.  Also, `TableA as a3 ON b.fkeyA3 = a1.id`?  I think your join is going to be a little haywire; `a2` and `a3` will be cross-joining - you don't need to join to `TableA` two more times - substitute `OR` conditions for the remaining two columns (and update the `COALESCE()`) and you should be good.

Comment: @X-Zero I did not know Coalesce took more than 2 parameters. The goal for the original joins were for them to be a1, a2, and a3 respectively, but using one with the `ON` clause was better.  Thanks for teaching me a thing or two tonight :)